# Struts2: How do I do a comparison using a HashMap's key inside an iterator

Tags: java, struts2, iterator, hashmap, comparison

I'm trying to display a radio button group, but I can't use the `<s:radio />` tag because I have to do some custom formatting. Because of this I have to manually set the checked input, but I'm not sure how I can compare the current position of the HashMap's key with the expected value. This is what I have so far, but it does not work:

```
<s:iterator value="frequencyList" var="freqVar">
     <label class="label_radio" for="frequencyStr">
        <s:if test="%{frequencyStr == freqVar.getKey()}">
              <input type="radio" name="frequencyStr" checked="checked" onchange="switchFrequencyOption()" 
                    value ="<s:property value="key" />" />
        </s:if>
        <s:else>
            <input type="radio" name="frequencyStr" onchange="switchFrequencyOption()" 
                     value ="<s:property value="key" />" />
        </s:else>
        <s:property value="value" /> 
    </label><br /> 
 </s:iterator>
```

Does anyone know what I can place in the `<s:if>` tag's test attribute to get the correct comparison?

Comment: What's wrong with `s:radio`?

Comment: sorry...unable to understand your question...

Comment: What is `frequencyStr`? And why `freqVar.getKey()` not just `key`?

Comment: `frequencyStr` is a server side variable, and it's value is what's used to preselect the correct radio button. Changing `freqVar.getKey()` to just `key` did the trick though. I wasn't sure if you could do it that way, or if the iterator `var` attribute needed to be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:iterator value="frequencyList">
    <label class="label_radio">
        <input type="radio" 
               name="frequencyStr" 
               value ="<s:property value="key" />"
               onchange="switchFrequencyOption()" 
            <s:if test="%{frequencyStr.equals(key)}">
               checked="checked"
            </s:if>
        />
        <s:property value="value" /> 
    </label>
    <br />
</s:iterator>
```